# Interpreting $\lim_{z\to x}\dfrac{\dfrac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}-f'(x)}{z-x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

I stumbled upon the limit as shown in the title some time ago. Evaluating the limit is not hard --
$\lim_{z\to x}\dfrac{\dfrac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}-f'(x)}{z-x}\\
=\lim_{z\to x}\dfrac{f(z)-f(x)-(z-x)f'(x)}{(z-x)^2}\\
\stackrel{\text{L'Hopital's}}{=}\dfrac{1}{2}f''(x)$.

What puzzles me is after I rearrange the equation --

$f''(x)=\lim_{z\to x}\dfrac{\dfrac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}-f'(x)}{\dfrac{1}{2}(z-x)}$,

I have a hard time convincing myself of the denominator. The second derivative can be regarded as the difference of the slopes $f'(a),f'(b)$ per the distance between them while $b$ approaches $a$.

In the equation above, we consider the slope at $x$ and another somewhere between $x$ and $z$ (by MVT) but we never know if it is halfway through.

So how do we make sense of $\dfrac{1}{2}(z-x)$? Why is it not some other fractions or even a varying fraction depending on $z$, $x$, and the function itself?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}$ is the slope of the secant line from $A(x,f(x))$ to $B(z,f(z))$ and that $f'(x)$ is the slope of the tangent line at $A$. Therefore
$$\lim_{z\to x}\dfrac{\dfrac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}-f'(x)}{z-x}$$
can be interpreted as the changing rate when the secant line $AB$ become the tangent line.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the Taylor Series expansion of $f(z)$ around $x$:

$$ f(z) = f(x) + f'(x)(z-x) + \frac{1}{2}f''(x)(z-x)^2 + \cdots $$

We can reproduce your second equation by rearranging:

$$ f(z) - f(x) = f'(x)(z-x) + \frac{1}{2}f''(x)(z-x)^2 + \cdots $$

$$\frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x} = f'(x) + \frac{1}{2}f''(x)(z-x) + \cdots $$

$$\frac{\frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}-f'(x)}{z-x} = \frac{1}{2}f''(x) + \cdots $$

$$\frac{\frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}-f'(x)}{\frac{1}{2}(z-x)} = f''(x) + \cdots $$

The omitted terms go to zero as $z\rightarrow x$, so in the limit we recover your second equation.